# React Native - loop through key value array

Tags: javascript, reactjs, react-native, ecmascript-6

How do i loop through this array and display the key ("ETH_SAN", "ETH_LINK") into  components?

```
{
  ETH_SAN: 
   { last: '0.000981',
     high: '0.0010763',
     low: '0.0009777',
     lowestAsk: '0.00098151',
     highestBid: '0.0007853',
     percentChange: '-1.83619353',
     baseVolume: '7.3922603247161',
     quoteVolume: '7462.998433' },
  ETH_LINK: 
   { last: '0.001',
     high: '0.0014',
     low: '0.001',
     lowestAsk: '0.002',
     highestBid: '0.001',
     percentChange: '-28.57142857',
     baseVolume: '13.651606265667369466',
     quoteVolume: '9765.891979953083752189' }
  // all possible markets follow ...
}
```

So it prints out this:

```
<Text>ETH_SAN</Text>
<Text>ETH_LINK</Text>
```

Comment: This is not an array.

Comment: something like: `Object.keys('yourObjectName').map((key) => <Text>{key}</Text>)`?

Comment: that worked @gaback - Thanks!

Comment: Great, that's help! @Nickmcoomb `Mikhail Katrin` is with the same solution and he saw this just like me and took time to write the code. Could you accept his answer? Thanks!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You could use [`Object.keys()`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Object/keys)

```js
const obj = {
  ETH_SAN: 
   { last: '0.000981',
     high: '0.0010763',
     low: '0.0009777',
     lowestAsk: '0.00098151',
     highestBid: '0.0007853',
     percentChange: '-1.83619353',
     baseVolume: '7.3922603247161',
     quoteVolume: '7462.998433' },
  ETH_LINK: 
   { last: '0.001',
     high: '0.0014',
     low: '0.001',
     lowestAsk: '0.002',
     highestBid: '0.001',
     percentChange: '-28.57142857',
     baseVolume: '13.651606265667369466',
     quoteVolume: '9765.891979953083752189' }
  // all possible markets follow ...
}

const keys = Object.keys(obj);

console.log(keys);

// add following line in your render() method
//Object.keys(obj).map(key => <Text>{key}</Text>)
```

Answer (score 1):

Use this below

```
 const data = {
      ETH_SAN: 
       { last: '0.000981',
         high: '0.0010763',
         low: '0.0009777',
         lowestAsk: '0.00098151',
         highestBid: '0.0007853',
         percentChange: '-1.83619353',
         baseVolume: '7.3922603247161',
         quoteVolume: '7462.998433' },
      ETH_LINK: 
       { last: '0.001',
         high: '0.0014',
         low: '0.001',
         lowestAsk: '0.002',
         highestBid: '0.001',
         percentChange: '-28.57142857',
         baseVolume: '13.651606265667369466',
         quoteVolume: '9765.891979953083752189' }
      // all possible markets follow ...
    }

//Step 1:    
    for(key in data){
       <Text>{key}</Text>
    }
    or
//Step 2:
   Object.keys(myObj).forEach(function (key) {
    let obj = myObj[key];
     <Text>{key}</Text>
    // do something with obj
  });
```

https://esdiscuss.org/topic/es6-iteration-over-object-values